# Laravel unit test how to test Event with email without send an email

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

how can I test this snippet without send an email ?

```
public function forgot() 
    {
        $isValid = $this->updateForm->valid(Input::only('email'));
        if ($isValid) {
            $result = $this->user->forgot($this->updateForm->data());
            if (isset($result['user']) && ($result['success'] > 0)) {
                Event::fire('user.mail.forgot', array('data'=>$result['user']));
                return Response::json(array('success'=>1),200);
            } 
            $error = isset($result['error'])?array_pop($result):trans('user.generror');
            return Response::json(array(
              'success'=>0,
              'errors' => array('error'=>array($error))),  
            200);
        }
        return Response::json(array(
                    'success' => 0,
                    'errors' => $this->updateForm->errors()), 
                    200
        );
    }
```

by now I test it with:

```
public function _getSuccess($content)
{
    $json = str_replace(")]}',\n", '', $content);
    $native = json_decode($json);
    return $native->success;
}
public function _set200($method, $uri, $parameters = array())
{
    $this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    $response = $this->call($method, $uri, $parameters);
    $this->assertResponseStatus(200);
    return $response;
}
public function testUserForgot200Success()
{
    $response = $this->_set200('POST', '/api/v1/users/forgot', array('email' => $this->userEmail));
    $this->assertSame(1, $this->_getSuccess($response->getContent()));
}
```

but in this way I have to set up the mail config file in the testing folder and the sustem send an a email :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `app/config/testing/mail.php` file and set pretend to true on it:

```
<?php

return [

    'pretend' => true,

];
```

Answer (score 5):

I needed to do that in Laravel 5 so in case someone needs it, here's a solution:

In `config/mail.php` replace this:

`'pretend' => false,`

by this:

`'pretend' => env('MAIL_PRETEND', false),`

Then you can override this environment variable in `phpunit.xml`:

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <!-- Add this line: -->
    <env name="MAIL_PRETEND" value="true" />
</php>
```

You can also override it in the `.env` file if you need, but it won't affect phpunit.